Chrome Should Skip DNS and Trust Proxy
I have a proxy.pac script setup to proxy a single domain (example.com) - everything else is DIRECT. It works fine in FireFox but Chrome fails on example.com with DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.
My diagnosis is that Chrome is failing at the DNS level and not even trying the proxy. Can I force Chrome to trust the proxy and not do any DNS?
Note:

I have tried clearing the cache in chrome://net-internals/#dns
I have tried all options/buttons to clear/reapply settings in chrome://net-internals/#proxy


Try this: First, disable dns over https, then launch Chrome with the --host-resolver-rules flag to force Chrome to resolve DNS through the proxy. See if this works, but no guarantee.

DNS over HTTPS could be the issue- do you use it/ have it on? You probably will, ON is the default.
